# Как исправить ошибку "Выражение должно иметь константное значение"? с++

Tags: c++, строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить так, чтобы slovar [q] был именно такого размера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, использовать

```
vector<string> slovar(q);
```

Comment: Опять минусятор прошёлся... Нормальный ответ же...

Comment: @zcorvid Привычное дело :)

Answer (score 0):

можете динамический массив стрингов использовать, а лучше как сказано выше использовать шаблон vector

```
    string *slovar = new string[q];
    delete[] slovar;
```